# Consolidate photos and eliminate duplicates?

Tags: digital, macintosh, file-management

I have a client who is having a lot of trouble managing his photos.  He has multiple copies in multiple Aperture and iPhoto libraries, imports from old PCs, etc.  What I'm looking for is a piece of software for OS X that can grab all these photos and reorganize them by EXIF data, say into YYYY/YYYY-MM-DD/*.jpg, eliminating duplicates as it goes.  Does such a thing exist?

Comment: I imagine they exist, but I don't know what they are for the Mac platform.  I'm pretty sure I can do that with a plug in for Total Commander on Windows, but that doesn't really help you.

Comment: AJ, can you elaborate?  I might be able to make a Windows solution work...

Comment: Maybe a bash script can do the job. There is command line tool in Mac OS X, called `mdls` that lists the metadata attributes for a specified file. You can create a bash script that recursively goes through the folders and renames the files based on `mdls` metadata. The good thing is that it works with raw files as well. To make more user-friendly, you can joint this solution with `Automator` to create a service or an application.

Comment: @Pouya If you had both an unconverted RAW version and a converted JPEG with the same EXIF info would it flag them as duplicates?

Comment: @MichaelClark, Short answer is no (unless you want it :D). In detail: it depends on how you implement the script. My comment was more guideline rather a complete answer. If you want the raw and jpeg be consider as duplicate you simply need to add an `or` condition. The duplication is indicated based on the file name and exif data is only necessary to rename them so that should not be a problem.

Comment: @Pouya thanks for the heads up on mdls, very handy, I did not know that one (have used exiftool previously, but that is an extra install).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off make backups of everything (especially when trusting strangers on the internet to help you :-)

iPhoto/Aperture store the photos in libraries which are semi-opaque. So they need to be exported, your first choice will be if you want to export the originals or a version of your photos with any edits you may have made in Aperture -- this is your choice, edited versions will obviously have any fixes you made in them, but if you edited out something, it will be lost (for example you crop me out of a picture).

1. In Aperture with a library open, select all the projects [image: Aperture with projects selected]
2. Right click and select export (here is where you need to choose the **Original** or **Version**) [image: Export Menu in Aperture]
3. Now you have the export dialog [image]
4. Select the location you want to use to collect all your images (be sure there is enough disk space to hold everything).
5. Select the **Export Preset** of **JPEG - Original Size**
6. In the **Subfolder Format** select **Edit...** [image: Subfolder Naming Dialog]
7. Create an export folder preset to match your desired format - click the **+** at the bottom left and then drag the Image Year, add a slash, etc.
8. In the **Name Format** selection, pick this and select **Edit...** [image: Name Format Dialog]
9. Create an option to export with the original file name.
10. Click the **Export Versions** or **Export Originals**
11. Rinse and repeat for all your libraries

Comment: +1 for "...especially when trusting strangers on the internet to help you..."

Answer (score 0):

Picasa has a really useful (experimental) feature called "show duplicate files". It should work with pictures that are rescaled or slightly cropped too I guess.

Then you can *manually* delete all but one copy of each.